# how to prevent all table rows from toggleing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a table that displays detailed (hidden) information beneath certain rows. When said row is clicked the table rows should show below the clicked row.

currently I have the shown rows in a class and the hidden rows in a class.

```
$("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
    $(this).next("tr.hist").toggle();
});
```

When the odd row is clicked the hist rows should pop out underneath it. However, only the first row shows up. I'm not sure how to get it to work with multiple hidden rows.

Here is a portion of my HTML:

`
        
            Select
                Cable #
                Source
                Destination
                Modified
                Location

```
    <tr class="odd">
            <td align="center"><input name="selectThis[]" type="checkbox" value="7435" id="selectThis[]"/></td>
            <td align="center" >bE4&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">5B04&nbsp;</td>
            <td>JOHN'S PC / RM. 58&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">                
            <td align="center"><input name="selectThis[]" type="checkbox" value="7436" id="selectThis[]"/></td>
            <td align="center" >bE5&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">5B05&nbsp;</td>
            <td>BRAD'S PC / RM. 58&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class="odd">                
            <td align="center"><input name="selectThis[]" type="checkbox" value="7437" id="selectThis[]"/></td>
            <td align="center" >bE6&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">5B06&nbsp;</td>
            <td>JAMES' PC / RM. 58&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='odd'>                
            <td align="center"><input name="selectThis[]" type="checkbox" value="7438" id="selectThis[]"/></td>
            <td align="left" >&nbsp;<span style='cursor:pointer'><left><img src='images/arrow.png'></left></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;bE7&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">5B07&nbsp;</td>
            <td>JR'S PC / RM. 58&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>video</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>video</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>video</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>audio</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='odd'>
            <td align="center"><input name="selectThis[]" type="checkbox" value="1663" id="selectThis[]"/></td>
            <td align="left" >&nbsp;<span style='cursor:pointer'><left><img src='images/arrow.png'></left></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;V7&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left">Bob Dylan&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Highway 61 Revisited&nbsp;</td>
            <td>12/05/2011&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>

     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>video</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class='hist'>
            <td>video</td>
            <td>Bob Dylan</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class='hist'>
          <td>video</td>
          <td>Bob Dylan</td>
      </tr>

 </body>
```

**MORE INFO**

How could I modify this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
        $("#report tr.odd").show();

        $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
            $(this).next("tr.hist").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I get the all of the HIST rows below it to show up and not just the first one?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple hidden rows" ?

Comment: i thought about wrapping all of the hidden rows in a <div> tag, so i would be able to toggle the next div instead of the next row. so all the <tr class="hist">s would all toggle together and not just the first one.

Comment: in my table most of the rows are under the "odd" class. however, some are under "hist" and they are hidden below their respective "odd" rows. when i use this script, only the first "hist" row shows up below the "odd" row because it's just going to the next <tr>. 

I need to find a way to select all the hidden "hist"<tr>s below an "odd", but not throughout the entire table

Comment: another theory was to use nextUntil and toggle the "hist" rows until it hit an "odd".

Comment: Don't wrap your `<tr>` with `<div>`, you html will not be valid anymore. Check the answers below.

Comment: my source code is working in jfiddle. what could i be doing wrong in the rest of my code that is causing this not to work?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function...

```
    $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil("tr.odd, tr.even").toggle();
    });
```

As you can clearly see, you can check for more than one class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).nextAll("tr.hist").toggle(); // for all subsequent

$(this).nextUntil(":not(tr.hist)").toggle();  // for subsequent adjacent
```

Comment: the first one does what i dont want. it shows all of the hidden rows at once.

Comment: the nextUntil seems to make sense when I look at it, but it's not working within my code. nothing happens when the row is clicked.

Comment: @user1082281: I'll take your word for it. You didn't provide any HTML in the question to give guidance. As far as I could tell, you had these groups separated into individual `<tbody>` elements (which might be a good approach for you anyway).

Comment: @user1082281: The `nextUntil` works when I test it. Try `nextUntil("tr:not(.hist)")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jQuery's nextUntil function, like this : http://jsfiddle.net/zSAdR/1/

**Update**

I edited my jsFiddle with the HTML you provided. It works, but you should think about either inserting some empty table-cells in your `.hist` rows or at least use the `colspan` attribute to avoid your table from breaking apart.

http://jsfiddle.net/zSAdR/9/

Comment: this is exactly what I want. but it's not working within my code.

Comment: You should show us your HTML code too if you want anybody to be able to help you more.

Comment: I'll gladly try to help you if you show us your HTML code. Without it, nobody can help you more than showing you a working jsFiddle of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I can get it to work in jfiddle, but not in my code.

i would post the HMTL, but its very large and uses a lot of php to connect to a database. i dont want to post it all and i dont know if pieces of it will make sense out of context

Comment: Unless you are manipulating the DOM with Javascript after page load, you could just copy/paste the computed HTML using "View source" on your web page. Your PHP code is, indeed, not related to the question. And if it's very large, start by posting only your table HTML.

Comment: i know, it's just place holder data for now until i can get it working. i also got my code to work in jsFiddle, but it doesn't want to work in my code. i'm getting really frustrated now. what is the proper way to include jquery? maybe i'm doing something wrong there. did you change anything major when you got it to work in jsFiddle?